# Rails 4 and FactoryGirl traits creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-4

We are migrate rails3 app to Rails4. In FactoryGirl we use this trait:

```
trait :with_student do
    after_create do |resource|
      resource.students << FactoryGirl.create(:student)
    end
  end
```

In model rspec:

```
  let(:course_with_student) { create(:course, :with_student) }
```

I raised course_with_student and gives me course object. But when raise  course_with_student.students output is:
 `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`. Raise exception in trait definition resource.students and student object is there, but not in rspec model spec.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually use the trait is in an `after_build` block. Have a go at something like this:

```
trait :with_student do
  after_build do |course|
    course.students = FactoryGirl.create_list(:student, 1)
  end
end
```

For me that solves some similar problems that I ran into.